# How to remove 0's from a Figure Name if its not in a Subsection, etc

Tags: floats, chngcntr

I use the chngcntr Package to Name my figures accordingly.

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsubsection}
\counterwithin{figure}{paragraph}
```

My Problem is when a Figure is, for example, only in a subsection and not in a subsubsection and paragraph the Figure name looks like this: Figure 1.1.0.0.1. But i want to look like this: Figure 1.1.1
If anybody can help that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: But how you would distinguish section 1 subsection 0 subsubsection 1 from section 1 subsection 1 subsubsection 0 ?

Comment: Apart from the fact that only the last command is actually doing something, the result will completely confound any reader.

Comment: @Teepeemm you are right that would be a problem, but luckily this doesnt happen in my document. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: What is the use case? Why should the presence or absence of a `\subparagraph` (with or without a figure) have any effect on the numbering of any previous figures? A recipe for readers' incomprehension.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it. But think twice (or, better, more times) whether to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of} % just for the example

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsubsection}
\counterwithin*{figure}{paragraph}
\newcommand{\notifzero}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}>0
    \arabic{#1}.%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
  \notifzero{section}%
  \notifzero{subsection}%
  \notifzero{subsubsection}%
  \notifzero{paragraph}%
  \arabic{figure}%
}

\begin{document}

\captionof{figure}{A}

\section{B}

\captionof{figure}{C}

\subsection{D}

\captionof{figure}{E}

\subsubsection{F}

\captionof{figure}{G}

\paragraph{H} Some text

\captionof{figure}{I}

\section{J}

\captionof{figure}{K}

\end{document}
```

I used `\captionof` just to make a shorter picture (otherwise several figures would require more pages).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that employs the `ifthen` package and its `\ifthenelse` macro. It works for `figure` as well as for table numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\counterwithin{figure}{paragraph}
\counterwithin{table}{paragraph}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{ifthen,etoolbox}
\newcommand\figandtabnums{%
\ifthenelse{\value{subsection}=0}{%
   \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}%
   \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}}{%
   \ifthenelse{\value{subsubsection}=0}{%
      \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesubsection.\arabic{figure}}%
      \renewcommand\thetable{\thesubsection.\arabic{table}}}{%
      \ifthenelse{\value{paragraph}=0}{%
         \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{figure}}%
         \renewcommand\thetable{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{table}}}{%
            \renewcommand\thefigure{\theparagraph.\arabic{figure}}%
            \renewcommand\thetable{\theparagraph.\arabic{table}}}}}}
\pretocmd{\caption}{\figandtabnums}{}{} 
  
\begin{document}
\section{Buenos días}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{First figure}\label{fig:uuu} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{First table}\label{tab:uuu} \end{table}

\subsection{Bonjour}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{Second figure}\label{fig:vvv} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Second table}\label{tab:vvv} \end{table}

\subsubsection{Buon giorno}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{Third figure}\label{fig:www} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Third table}\label{tab:www} \end{table}

\paragraph{Kaliméra} What a day!
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{Fourth figure}\label{fig:xxx} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Fourth table}\label{tab:xxx} \end{table}

\bigskip
Cross-references to Figures \ref{fig:uuu}, \ref{fig:vvv}, \ref{fig:www}, and \ref{fig:xxx}.

Cross-references to Tables \ref{tab:uuu}, \ref{tab:vvv}, \ref{tab:www}, and \ref{tab:xxx}.
\end{document}
```